# Web socket chat and EJB services

Tags: java, websocket, ejb-3.1, java-ee-7, inject

I'm new JavaEE/EJB developer. I want to create a chat service for my web application. The main functionality of the chat feature is to send a simple message to user depend on some events.
Here is the code:

**Chat endpoint**

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat")
public class ChatEndpoint {


    @OnOpen
    public void open(final Session session, final EndpointConfig config) {

    }

    @OnMessage
    public void message(final String msg) {

    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {

    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(final Session session) {

    }

    public void sendMessage(@Observes ChatEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Try to dispatch new message: " + event.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**Event class**

```
public class ChatEvent {

    private final String message;

    public ChatEvent(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

**Timer class** (To send some random messages)

```
@Stateless
public class ChatTimer {

    @Inject
    Event<ChatEvent> events;

    @Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    public void sendSomeRandomeMessage(){
        System.out.println("Send event");
        events.fire(new ChatEvent("from bean " + System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

}
```

Now my question is:

1. Is there any problem to create @ServerEndpoint as @Stateless (Because without @Stateless, @Observes method does not work)
2. How can I track all the open session (users) to broadcast a message to them? (My current strategy is to save them in static field that seems not right!)

Comment: 1) Did you try? 2) Yes, that is fine.

Comment: Rather than using a static field you might consider a separate `@ApplicationScoped` bean to keep track of your active sessions, that would allow potentially allow you to support multiple transport types and separate your session management from your transport beans.

Comment: 1) I did add it, it works, at least with simple test but I thought that maybe cause some problem for conflict with something else.
2) Can I broadcast something to tens of thousands users or more with static field or by using @ApplicationScoped?

Comment: Scale depends on a ton of different items but your choice of `@ApplicationScoped` vs static won't affect that. If you expect to scale beyond the capabilities of a single server you'll need some way to store your sessions externally in something like memcached or other name/value store.